# Python list of tuples merge 2nd element with unique first element

Tags: python, list, merge, tuples, unique

Given a list of tuples like so:

```
a = [ ( "x", 1, ), ( "x", 2, ), ( "y", 1, ), ( "y", 3, ), ( "y", 4, ) ]
```

What would be the easiest way to filter for unique first element and merge the second element.  An output like so would be desired.

```
b = [ ( "x", 1, 2 ), ( "y", 1, 3, 4 ) ]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(tuple)
>>> a = [('x', 1), ('x', 2), ('y', 1), ('y', 3), ('y', 4)]
>>> for tup in a:
...     d[tup[0]] += (tup[1],)
...
>>> [tuple(x for y in i for x in y) for i in d.items()]
[('y', 1, 3, 4), ('x', 1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> a = [("x", 1,), ("x", 2,), ("y", 1,), ("y", 3,), ("y", 4,)]
>>> d = {}
>>> for k, v in a:
...     d.setdefault(k, [k]).append(v)
>>> b = map(tuple, d.values())
>>> b
[('y', 1, 3, 4), ('x', 1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
[tuple(list(el) + [q[1] for q in a if q[0]==el]) for el in set([q[0] for q in a])]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answers, another one-liner:

```
>>> a = [ ( "x", 1, ), ( "x", 2, ), ( "y", 1, ), ( "y", 3, ), ( "y", 4, ) ]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [(key,) + tuple(elem for _, elem in group) for key, group in groupby(a, lambda pair: pair[0])]
[('x', 1, 2), ('y', 1, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using *list comprehension* expression with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) , [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, chain
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> my_list = [ ( "x", 1, ), ( "x", 2, ), ( "y", 1, ), ( "y", 3, ), ( "y", 4, ) ]

>>> [set(chain(*i)) for _, i in groupby(sorted(my_list), key=itemgetter(0))]
[set(['x', 2, 1]), set(['y', 1, 3, 4])]
```

**Note:** `set` are unordered in nature, so they won't preserve the position of elements. Do not use `set` if the position matters.