# Sort and combine tuples by repeated elements

Tags: python, sorting, combinations

I have a list that resembles this one:

```
a = [(2, 'T'), (0, 'W'), (1, 'J'), (0, 'V'), (2, 'C')]
```

and I need to convert it into this:

```
b = [(0, 'W', 'V'), (1, 'J'), (2, 'T', 'C')]
```

This is: sort it by the first element in each tuple, and combine into a single tuple all those with repeated first elements.

I could do this with some convoluted use of `for`, but I'm wondering if there might be an easier/simpler way (perhaps using `zip()` and `sorted()`?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909280/python-list-of-tuples-merge-2nd-element-with-unique-first-element this is an ideal case for a groupby

Comment: Well this is a very clear duplicate of that question @PadraicCunningham, thank you for pointing it out. Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Since you need to sort the result at the end it's better to use `groupby()` `>>> [tuple(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(g))) for _,g in groupby(sorted(a, key=itemgetter(0)), itemgetter(0))]
[(0, 'W', 'V'), (1, 'J'), (2, 'T', 'C')]
`

Comment: Good one liner. You should add it to the older question @Kasramvd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [(2, 'T'), (0, 'W'), (1, 'J'), (0, 'V'), (2, 'C')]

b = defaultdict(list)

for v in a:
    b[v[0]].append(v[1])

b = [tuple([k] + [b[k]]) for k in sorted(b.keys())]
print b
```