# Unique ordered ratio of integers

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have two ordered lists of consecutive integers m=0, 1, ... M  and n=0, 1, 2, ... N. Each value of m has a probability pm, and each value of n has a probability pn.  I am trying to find the ordered list of unique values r=n/m and their probabilities pr.    I am aware that r is infinite if n=0 and can even be undefined if m=n=0.

In practice, I would like to run for M and N  each be of the order of 2E4, meaning up to 4E8 values of r - which would mean 3 GB of floats (assuming 8 Bytes/float).

For this calculation, I have written the python code below.

The idea is to iterate over m and n, and for each new m/n, insert it in the right place with its probability if it isn't there yet, otherwise add its probability to the existing number.  My assumption is that it is easier to sort things on the way instead of waiting until the end.

The cases related to 0 are added at the end of the loop.

I am using the Fraction class since we are dealing with fractions.

The code also tracks the multiplicity of each unique value of m/n.

I have tested up to M=N=100, and things are quite slow.  Are there better approaches to the question, or more efficient ways to tackle the code?

Timing:

- M=N=30: 1 s
- M=N=50: 6 s
- M=N=80: 30 s
- M=N=100: 82 s

```
    import numpy as np
    from fractions import Fraction
    import time # For timiing
    
    start_time = time.time() # Timing
    
    M, N = 6, 4
    mList, nList = np.arange(1, M+1), np.arange(1, N+1) # From 1 to M inclusive, deal with 0 later
    mProbList, nProbList = [1/(M+1)]*(M), [1/(N+1)]*(N) # Probabilities, here assumed equal (not general case)
    
    # Deal with mn=0 later
    pmZero, pnZero = 1/(M+1), 1/(N+1) # P(m=0) and P(n=0)
    pNaN = pmZero * pnZero # P(0/0) = P(m=0)P(n=0)
    pZero = pmZero * (1 - pnZero) # P(0) = P(m=0)P(n!=0)
    pInf = pnZero * (1 - pmZero) # P(inf) = P(m!=0)P(n=0)
    
    # Main list of r=m/n, P(r) and mult(r)
    # Start with first line, m=1
    rList = [Fraction(mList[0], n) for n in nList[::-1]] # Smallest first
    rProbList = [mProbList[0] * nP for nP in nProbList[::-1]] # Start with first line
    rMultList = [1] * len(rList) # Multiplicity of each element
    
    # Main loop
    for m, mP in zip(mList[1:], mProbList[1:]):
        for n, nP in zip(nList[::-1], nProbList[::-1]): # Pick an n value
            r, rP, rMult = Fraction(m, n), mP*nP, 1
            for i in range(len(rList)-1): # See where it fits in existing list
                if r < rList[i]:
                    rList.insert(i, r)
                    rProbList.insert(i, rP)
                    rMultList.insert(i, 1)
                    break
                elif r == rList[i]:
                    rProbList[i] += rP
                    rMultList[i] += 1
                    break
                elif r < rList[i+1]:
                    rList.insert(i+1, r)
                    rProbList.insert(i+1, rP)
                    rMultList.insert(i+1, 1)
                    break
                elif r == rList[i+1]:
                    rProbList[i+1] += rP
                    rMultList[i+1] += 1
                    break
            if r > rList[-1]:
                rList.append(r)
                rProbList.append(rP)
                rMultList.append(1)
                break
    
    # Deal with 0
    rList.insert(0, Fraction(0, 1))
    rProbList.insert(0, pZero)
    rMultList.insert(0, N)
    
    # Deal with infty
    rList.append(np.Inf)
    rProbList.append(pInf)
    rMultList.append(M)
    
    # Deal with undefined case
    rList.append(np.NAN)
    rProbList.append(pNaN)
    rMultList.append(1)
    
    print(".... done in %s seconds." % round(time.time() - start_time, 2))
    
    print("************** Final list\nr", 'Prob', 'Mult')
    for r, rP, rM in zip(rList, rProbList, rMultList): print(r, rP, rM)
        
    print("************** Checks")
    print("mList", mList, 'nList', nList)
    print("Sum of proba = ", np.sum(rProbList))
    print("Sum of multi = ", np.sum(rMultList), "\t(M+1)*(N+1) = ", (M+1)*(N+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion of @Prune, and on this [thread about merging lists of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909280/python-list-of-tuples-merge-2nd-element-with-unique-first-element), I have modified the code as below.  It's a lot easier to read, and runs about an order of magnitude faster for N=M=80 (I have omitted dealing with 0 - would be done same way as in original post).  I assume there may be ways to tweak the merge and conversion back to lists further yet.

```
# Do calculations
data = [(Fraction(m, n), mProb(m) * nProb(n)) for n in range(1, N+1) for m in range(1, M+1)]
data.sort()

# Merge duplicates using a dictionary
d = {}
for r, p in data:
    if not (r in d): d[r] = [0, 0]
    d[r][0] += p
    d[r][1] += 1

# Convert back to lists
rList, rProbList, rMultList = [], [], []
for k in d:
    rList.append(k)
    rProbList.append(d[k][0])
    rMultList.append(d[k][1])
```

Comment: Will accept this as answer unless further suggestions for the merge and conversion back to lists

Answer (score 0):

I expect that "things are quite slow" because you've chosen a known inefficient sort.  A single list insertion is **O(K)** (later list elements have to be bumped over, and there is added storage allocation on a regular basis).  Thus a full-list insertion sort is **O(K^2)**.  For your notation, that is **O((M*N)^2)**.

If you want any sort of reasonable performance, research and use the best-know methods.  The most straightforward way to do this is to make your non-exception results as a simple list comprehension, and use the built-in sort for your penultimate list.  Simply append your `n=0` cases, and you're done in **O(K log K)** time.

I the expression below, I've assumed functions for `m` and `n` probabilities.
This is a notational convenience; you know how to directly compute them, and can substitute those expressions if you wish.

```
data = [ (mProb(m) * nProb(n), Fraction(m, n))
       for n in range(1, N+1)
           for m in range(0, M+1) ]
data.sort()
data.extend([ # generate your "zero" cases here ])
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.  Are you saying that duplicates should be dealt with after the ```data.sort()```, ie once things are sorted, look for consecutive duplicates, add the probabilities, and get rid of the extras?   I would have tried list(set()), but don't see how that would deal with the probabilities.

Comment: That's just how to deal with the duplicates: merge and sum them.  Good catch!

Comment: Couldn't figure out role of frac on your first line, have omitted it from follow up below (also ignored "zero" cases).