# How to merge list if there is a duplicate int found?

Tags: python

Suppose I have

```
transactions = [(1, ‘1 Jan 2021’,  ‘50usd’), (1, ‘1 Jan 2021’, ‘100usd’)]
```

the firsr value of the list is a transaction id followed by date and amount. If there is a duplicate id found in any lists, I would want to merge them like so:

```
[(1, ‘1 Jan 2021’, ‘50usd’, ‘1 Jan 2021’,  ‘100usd’)]
```

Please help, thanks.

Edit: the lists will be dynamic and more than thousands lists. Currently I am dumping all the lists into my postgres but I want this question to only be python related and I hope you have a rough idea of how inefficient my method is, so yup I basically dump all the data into postgres and at the end I’ll use pg syntax to find the duplicate id and merge them. I’m hoping to do this in Python then only dumping them into my db. Hope that helps.

Comment: Have you come up with an inefficient way of doing this?  Then we can help you refine to achieve your goal.

Comment: Currently I am dumping all the lists into my postgres but I want this question to only be python related and also since you asked, so yup I basically dump all the data into postgres and at the end I’ll use pg syntax to find the duplicate id and merge them. I’m hoping to do this in Python then only dumping them into my db. Hope that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list of tuples merge 2nd element with unique first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909280/python-list-of-tuples-merge-2nd-element-with-unique-first-element)